# some portion of Bootstrap 3 navbar documentation not understood

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

the code is taken from bootsrap 3 documenation for navbar.

The following part class="navbar-header" is not understood well (no idea about sr-only, toggle navigation inside span). will any one explain purpose of that particular part?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
```

Comment: I've edited your post, because you cannot format code as bold (or something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this reference is not exactly for Toggle button of the `navbar` it explains the purpose of `.sr-only`:

> [[...] Screen readers will have trouble with your forms if you don't include a label for every input. For these inline forms, you can hide the labels using the `.sr-only` class. [...]"](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

`Toggle navigation` is not displayed as text but e.g. as three dashes and for screen readers there is the text.

Comment: Thankyou.what about class="icon-bar"? why three spans inside a button?

Comment: @violetkiwi If you make your window narrow a button with three dashes appears to toggle navigation, `icon-bar` is one dash.

Comment: @violetkiwi An additional note. Bootstrap uses media queries, so the layout - and therefore the also the visibility of some elements - changes depending on the dimension of the window, thats why you have some _additional_ html code with the bootstrap elements.